# Using utf8 characters in wildcard path in bash commands

Tags: bash, utf-8, wildcard

I have problem with using wildcard path with console comands on osx 10.11 (but i suppose it would be similar on linux)

I have structure of folders named by event and date in czech language.

I need to list the files in subfolders by months. I would like to use wildcards like that:

```
ls export/*prosince\ 2013/*
```

While this works, when i want to use utf8 in the wildcard i get "No such file or directory"

```
ls export/*září\ 2013/*
```

Locale looks properly

```
winsik:Fotky vita$ locale

LANG="cs_CZ.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="cs_CZ.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="cs_CZ.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="cs_CZ.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="cs_CZ.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="cs_CZ.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="cs_CZ.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

How is possible to use utf8 characters in the shell commands?

EDIT: I have found the strange situation, if I let the terminal to complete some UTF8 path with TAB key, and then use this characters, then it works, but when I type them by keyboard it doesn't - same behavior in terminal.app and iterm2.app

```
winsik:Fotky vita$ bind -v | grep meta
set convert-meta off
set input-meta on
set meta-flag on
set output-meta on
```

Comment: What are the meta variables in the Bash Readline config set to? IIRC `bind -V | grep meta`

Comment: Attached to the question, I have also currently found strange behaviour - see Edit

Comment: I can speculate that Bash uses different Unicode normalization than your system, but that would be a pretty serious bug. Or is it possible that the files are on a foreign file system with non-default or broken normalization? In other words, what are the encoded bytes in the file name, and when you type them at the prompt? Your terminal could also be the culprit, but if you are using the default terminal on the console, that seems even more unlikely.

Comment: What character encoding is your terminal emulator using? You may be entering text using a different encoding; the terminal still displays the correct glyphs, but `bash` is getting non-UTF-8 byte stream.

Answer (score 2):

Most Unicode systems use a form of Unicode normalization called "fully composed", whereas Apple typically uses "fully decomposed".  See [Unicode equivalence in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence) for background; but in short, there are two ways to represent an accented character like ř -- a precomposed, single code point ([U+0159](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0159/index.htm)), or a plain r ([U+0072](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0072/index.htm)) followed by a composing accent ([U+030C](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/030c/index.htm)) which is joined above the base letter by the font renderer.

If Unicode normalization is the problem, you would not be able to successfully repeat the following steps, I expect.  This is in Terminal on OSX Yosemite.

```
yosemite:~ tripleee$ touch 'Jiří'

yosemite:~ tripleee$ ls
Jiří

yosemite:~ tripleee$ printf '%s\n' *
Jiří

yosemite:~ tripleee$ printf '%s' * | xxd
0000000: 4a69 72cc 8c69 cc81                      Jir..i..

yosemite:~ tripleee$ rm 'Jiří'
```

(As you can tell from the linked page, the UTF-8 encoding of the joining caron U+030C is the two bytes 0xCC 0x8C.)

```
yosemite:~ tripleee$ perl -e 'open(F, "Ji\N{U+0159}\N{U+00ED}")'

yosemite:~ tripleee$ ls
Jiří

yosemite:~ tripleee$ printf '%s' * | xxd
0000000: 4a69 72cc 8c69 cc81                      Jir..i..
```

So as you can see, even though I specifically requested the precomposed characters U+0159 and U+00ED, the operating system normalized them to decomposed before creating the file.

This should really be a comment but I am posting it as a speculative answer in the hope that it can at least help you disprove this hypothesis.  If you can repeat this without issue, I guess we can rule out Unicode normalization as a possible source of the problem.

Comment: I was able to do that in the same steps (in the list here diacritic mark is not over letters, I can see them as usual: 'Jiří') But all codes are same. So I suppose terminal and normalization of input is ok. I will check the characters of directories itself - they are generated by Photos Application. So probably Iam trying to solve some others problem :)

Comment: Your comment says you see the diacritic separate, but the copy/paste "I can see them as usual: 'Jiří'" displays for me with the caron over the r, and the acute over the i.  Are you saying it looks different for you?

Comment: In your answer above I don't see caron and acute over r and i, but as separate character(I suppose its stackoverflow formating but). In terminal i see them normally above letters.

Comment: Sounds like something more fundamental is broken then.  Another shot in the dark: Are you perhaps using unusual fonts which lack Unicode support?

Comment: I have the same problem. I think tripleee is right, it's about the difference between precomposed and decomposed unicode. But its a bug in bash that is only getting trigged with things like wildcards and tab completion.

http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/10476/how-to-enter-special-characters-so-that-bash-terminal-understands-them